# Bean definition is overriden by AutoConfiguration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In my Spring application I have defined a bean of type `AuditListener`.

```
@Component
public class AuditListener {
}
```

My project also contains a dependency to `spring-boot-starter-actuator` which also defines a bean of type `AuditListener` via `AuditAutoConfiguration`.

When I try to start my application it fails because my own `AuditListener` is not available.

```
// successful
beanFactory.getBean(org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.listener.AuditListener.class);

// fails with NoSuchBeanDefinitionException
beanFactory.getBean(demo.AuditListener.class);
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute ApplicationRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:791)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:778)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243)
    at demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:14)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'demo.AuditListener' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:347)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:334)
    at demo.DemoApplication.run(DemoApplication.java:27)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:788)
    ... 11 more
```

The DefaultListableBeanFactory logs

> INFO 10140 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory 
>   : Overriding bean definition for bean 'auditListener' with a different
>   definition: replacing [Generic bean: class [demo.AuditListener];
>   scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0;
>   dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false;
>   factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null;
>   destroyMethodName=null; defined in file
>   [C:\workspace\spring-autoconfiguration-conflict-demo\target\classes\demo\AuditListener.class]]
>   with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false;
>   autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true;
>   primary=false;
>   factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.audit.AuditAutoConfiguration;
>   factoryMethodName=auditListener; initMethodName=null;
>   destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/audit/AuditAutoConfiguration.class]]

How can I get both `AuditListener` beans into my context without renaming my own?

edit: If I define two beans with same class name in different packages I get a ConflictingBeanDefinitionException, so the ApplicationContext won't even start.

Comment: Isn't this a use-case for Spring's ``@Qualifier`` annotation? https://spring.io/blog/2014/11/04/a-quality-qualifier

Comment: Are you averse to renaming your bean or your class? If you're OK with renaming your bean then `@Component("myAuditListener")` with `@Qualifier` to inject it.

Answer (score 1):

You can give a name to your bean so that it will not conflict with the `SpringBoot` bean

```
@Component(value = "myCustomAuditListener ")
public class AuditListener {
}
```

and then use `@Qualifies` to inject it by name `myCustomAuditListener`

Answer (score 0):

If a bean with the same bean name is added by an AutoConfiguration, Spring would remove your own bean from the context. That’s standard Spring Framework behaviour. When there are multiple beans declared with the same name, the last one that’s declared will win. Framework should log an info message to let you know that an override has taken place.